# Tracking the lowest score in a guessing game WITHOUT a list/array (Java)

Tags: java

I am stuck in a short program I've been working on. I need to find a way to store the best score (the lowest score) after the user has run the game multiple times. Here is the code for my program-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessingGame
{
public static void main(String[] args){


    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);

    String play = "";
    boolean playAgain = true;
    int playTimes = 0;
    int lowScore = 0; 
    int count = 0;

    do{
        int target = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

        System.out.print("\nEnter a number between 1 and 100: ");

        int guess = prompt.nextInt();

        while(guess != target){
            if(target > guess){
                System.out.println("The number is higher. Try again.");
                count++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The number is lower. Try again.");
                count++;
            }

        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
        guess = prompt.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("You guessed correctly! Congratulations!");
        count++;
        System.out.println("Your score is: " + count);



        System.out.print("\nWould you like to play again? Yes or no?: ");
        play = prompt.next();

        if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            playAgain = false;
        }
        else if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            count = 0;
            playAgain = true;
        }

        playTimes++;

        if(count < lowScore){
            lowScore = count;
        } 

    }while(playAgain);


    System.out.println("\nGame Summary");
    System.out.print("      Games played: " + playTimes);

    System.out.println("\n        Best Score: " +lowScore);
```

The issue is that I've been running this program and the "best score" keeps displaying 0. I've tried bringing my "if" statement outside of the while-loop but it continues displaying 0. Could anyone help with my logic?

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: Yeah that's because when you play a game `lowScore` is never gonna be greater than count at first. So therefore lowScore will always be... 0! Look at the code `if(count < lowScore) { lowScore = count;}` that will never be true

Comment: Shouldn't `count` be initialized before each game?

Comment: If the user enters "yes" to make playAgain true, count is reinitialized to 0.

Comment: What if the user enters "hello"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is initialized to be 0 and is only incremented, so it won't be negative unless overflow occurs.

`lowScore` is initialized to be 0 and any non-negative numbers are not less than, so `count < lowScore` has too little chance to be true.

You should initialize `lowScore` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or introduce a variable to remember if `lowScore` has a valid score like this:

```
int lowScore = 0;
int count = 0;
boolean isLowScoreValid = false; // the variable

if(!isLowScoreValid || count < lowScore){ // update if any value were't set
    lowScore = count;
    isLowScoreValid = true; // now a value is set
}

System.out.println("\n        Best Score: " +(isLowScoreValid ? lowScore : "(none)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initalize `lowScore` to the highest integer possible. Try
`int lowScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` and then run your program. Cheers!